# does compiling sass into css require me to have ruby command prompt open constantly?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

Okay, I know nothing of Ruby, I am building a PHP website and decided I would like to try SASS as an alternative to CSS. I only installed the RubyInstaller so I could use SASS.

I downloaded Ruby Installer for Windows, and then set sass to watch my project and compile .scss files into .css files, which worked, but as soon as I closed the terminal, it stopped working - so my question is, do I have to keep the Ruby terminal or whatever it is contantly open when updating my scss/css files, and if I do close it (in between sessions for example), do I have to retype `sass --watch thisfile:thisfile` etc.?

That seems a bit pointless, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I've googled for the life of me and no-one seems to mention it?

Comment: are you using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--watch` basically runs a process that watches for file changes, if you close the terminal window from which you ran it, the watching process is also closed. So, briefly, yes: you have to leave the terminal opened if you want the sass file to be compiled automatically.

Comment: That really takes the intuitiveness out of it, to be honest. I'd like to use SASS, but not have to lug around the task of constantly declaring a watch every time I turnoff my computer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well if you think about it, how would SASS know what or when to translate the files? The one possible option that I imagine would be an apache module (or nginx or whatever) that would read the .scss and translate on the fly, but I think it's cumbersome.

Comment: Okay - if I do decide to give it a chance, is there at least anyway for me to set a base location in the Ruby terminal, so I don't have to type out an entire directory structure to compile a single file?

Comment: I added a possible solution for this.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely true.  There are many ways to automate this.. I'm guessing this is a bit of knowledge a lot of dev's are not yet willing to expand upon for the general public.. not seeing many good solutions out there with people like Christoph below proposing users run nohup - that just isn't a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to reattach it somewhen later:
`nohup sass --watch thisfile:thisfile > sass.out 2> sass.err < /dev/null &`

Otherwise you could use screen to run it in an independent screen
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SCREEN

Comment: Yep, nohup is perfect for this.

Comment: Sounds good - but what is nohup, and will doing this allow me to watch a file indefinitely between sessions?